# phpmailer is working fine localhost but where as server

Tags: phpmailer

PHPmailer is working fine in localhost but when on server it shows SMTP error, previously it worked but fine but since recently it is not working. This problem occurs in all of my cPanels, could it be a reseller account server problem? I am using code below and I am getting error like: 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

```
function mail_sending($to_address, $to_name, $title_tag, $subject_tag, $mail_body) 
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //End Code for adding a Page
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                   // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "myhost.com";        // sets  the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465;                     // set the SMTP port
    $mail->Username = "admin@myhost.com";   // username
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mail->SetFrom('admin@myhost.com', $title_tag);

    $mail->Subject = $subject_tag;

    //End Attachments
    //Start code for sending a html Body
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $mail_body;
    //End code for sending a html Body
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
    $mail->AddAddress($to_address, $to_name);

    $mail->Send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it appears that the local server is requiring **authentication** information before it let's you send any mail.

You can specified said info like this:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = “email@domain.com”; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = “password”; // SMTP password
```

`username` and `password` should be the ones you got from your hosting provider regarding smtp usage, i am sure they got FAQs or can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your OpenSSL enabled in your Server:

```
1. Login through WHM with your root account;
2. Select or search for "EasyApache (Apache Update)";
3. Select "Start customizing based on profile";
4. Select "Next step";
5. Select "Next step";
6. Select "Next step";
7. Select "Exhaustive Options List";
8. Select "OpenSSL";
9. Select "Save and Build" and choose "Yes" in the following questions.
```

More information : http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/enable-php-openssl-machine-whm-cpanel-222991.html